# How do I get an Instagram user's profile photo via graph API for Basic Display?

Tags: instagram

I am trying to use the graph API to get the Instagram user's profile photo. This is an implementation of the Oauth2 api.

To get the profile information (username, id), I am using this: `GET https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username,media`

When I use the access token to get the media, I am using this endpoint: `GET https://graph.instagram.com/${profile.id}/media?fields=id,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url`

This seems to return the pictures and other media from the user's instagram account, but none of it is actually the profile picture.

Is there a simple way to get the user's profile photo via API? Which field do I need to request or which media do I explicitly need to look for?

Thanks!